# Why `itertools.repeat` always generate the same random number?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Compare the outputs of these two functions:

```
from itertools import repeat
def rand_list1():
    l = lambda: np.random.rand(3)
    return list(repeat(l(), 5))

def rand_list2():
    return [np.random.rand(3) for i in range(5)]
```

We see that `rand_list1` who uses `itetools.repeat` always generates the same 3 numbers. why is this? Can it be avoided, so each call of `rand_list()` will generate new numbers?

For example, the output of `rand_list1()`:

```
[[0.07678796 0.22623777 0.07533145]
 [0.07678796 0.22623777 0.07533145]
 [0.07678796 0.22623777 0.07533145]
 [0.07678796 0.22623777 0.07533145]
 [0.07678796 0.22623777 0.07533145]]
```

and the output of `rand_list2()`:

```
[[0.77863856 0.30345662 0.7007517 ]
 [0.56422447 0.97138115 0.47976387]
 [0.20576279 0.92875791 0.06518335]
 [0.2992384  0.89726684 0.16917078]
 [0.8440534  0.38016789 0.51691172]]
```

Comment: Please include what the output actually is, vs what the desired output is. The problem is likely that you are feeding the result of calling `l` to `repeat`, but it's not clear from your question what you are expecting to see.

Answer (score 3):

There is a basic miscomprehension on how the language works in your question.

With the lambda expression, you simply create a new function named `l`.

At the moment you do `l()` Python will call the function -  and it will return a value: it is the returned value that will be used in place of the expression `l()` in the remaining of the larger expression. So, in this case, you are actually calling `repeat` with a single, already generated, number as the first parameter.

FUnctions that are passed as arguments to be called on their destination, and then are run anew each time are an allowed construct in Python, but (1) they depend on the receiving function being able to use functions as arguments, and that is not the case of `repeat`, and (2) more importanty one has to pass the function name **without** typing in the **parentheses**.

In this case, `repeat` is redundant, as the universal syntax that allows one to call a function multiple times to create an iterator already does the repetition you thought `repeat` would create for you.

Just do:

```
return [l() for _ in range(5)]
```

This will call `l()` for each interaction of the loop.

(btw, one should strongly avoid `l` as a single variable or function name in any context, as in many fonts it ishard to distinguish `l` from `1`)

Answer (score 1):

## The reason why `list(repeat(l(), 5))` repeats the same value.

`itertools.repeat()` will just iterate the same result.

Because l() is assigned the result of `l()` in `list(repeat(l(), 5))` when the `l` is called (which means `l()`).

[itertools.repeat() document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

> repeat(10, 3) --> 10 10 10

So what is exactly going on?

stage 1

```
 list(repeat(l(), 5))
```

stage 2

```
 list(repeat([some numbers], 5))
```

stage 3

```
 list(repeat([some numbers], 5))   --> [some numbers], [some numbers], [some numbers], [some numbers], [some numbers]
```